# In HTML, why put a sectioning element inside a list?

Tags: html

Let's say there is a list which every `li` element has an article element inside.

Since the article element is a sectioning content element, would it split the list explicitly? If so, does the list conserve its purpose?

The [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) says `li` element accepts any flow content so any sectioning content would be allowed, and it would be validated, but won't it be better to put links to the articles instead of the articles?

The example uses the article element but I think It could be applied to every sectioning content element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question here is what would be the purpose of putting multiple `<article>` elements inside a `<li>`. I think that whatever you're trying to accomplish can be done in other ways. An article can contain lists; lists can contain links to articles; why put a sectioning element inside a list?

Your lists and articles certainly have CSS styles assigned to them. If you like the way your lists display content, you can arrange for your articles to look that way with CSS, without putting the latter inside the former. Inside of lists, `<p>` elements would be more appropriate, if you wanted to include more copy than just article links.

Here's a good reason why articles inside lists are semantically bogus. An [article tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_article.asp) "specifies independent, self-contained content." If you put that inside a list, it is no longer independent or self-contained; it is either related to, or dependent on, the other list items.